# Main class java does not return the value i passed in using scanner

Tags: java

I have this main class

```
public class Hotel
{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  Register[] items = new Register[15];
  int count = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    Hotel run = new Hotel();
    int quantity, sale,night;
    Register deluxe = new Deluxe();
    Register family = new Family();
    Register suite = new Suite();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter customer's name:");
    String name = input.next();

    run.enterItems();
    if(run.count != 0)
    {
    System.out.println("\nHotel Reservation Payment");
    System.out.println("============================");
    System.out.println("Customer name: " + name);
    deluxe.displayInfo(); //supposed to print the details
    family.displayInfo(); //supposed to print the details
    suite.displayInfo();  //supposed to print the details
    System.out.println("The final total is RM" + fmt.format(run.calcTotal()));
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("No items entered.");
      run.enterItems();
    }
 }

 public double calcTotal()
  {
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<count;i++)
    {
      total += items[i].total();
    }
    return total;
  }
```

that is supposed to return the value i put in in the scanner here in the `enterItems()` that is in the class as the main class

```
public void enterItems()
{
    int type, quantity, sale,night;
    double price;
  ............................

    System.out.println("\nNow please enter how many of Deluxe Room you want to book.");
    quantity = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\nHow many night?");
    night = scan.nextInt();
    items[count] = new Deluxe(quantity,sale,night);
    count++;
}
```

So this will pass to the class called `Deluxe` where i have this method called `displayInfo()`

```
public class Deluxe implements Register
{
int quantity,night;
double sale;
public Deluxe(){}

....................................

public double total()
{
    double total, price = 200.0;
    price = price*quantity*night;
    total = price - (price * (sale/100));
    total += total *.06;
    return total;
}

public void displayInfo(){
    if (quantity > 0){
    System.out.println("Room Type : Deluxe Room"); 
    System.out.println("Quantity: " +quantity);
    System.out.println("Discount: " +sale);
    }
 }
}
```

the problem is, in checking for `quantity > 0`, it actually does not get any value that i put in in the scanner. It will always return 0 for quantity regardless what amount i put in.
But the calculation works fine. Calculation is to calculate how many (quantity) rooms book x night stay x the room's price.
The calculation is also in the same class as the `displayInfo()` which is in class `Deluxe`.

So i was wondering what did i do wrong here.

Comment: Your displayInfo method has no access to the quantity variable, since it is a local variable within the main method. So this code won't compile.

Comment: I believe quantity is not a local variable. Can you show us where it's assigned? Also, the `Deluxe` class.

Comment: @A.Abramov did you see this part of the code? Quantity is declared the third line of the main method. public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    Hotel run = new Hotel();
    int quantity, sale,night;

Comment: @Stultuske Yeah, but the OP seems to compile it, they just say the quantity has nothing to do with the actual value, which means they compiled it to that point. I suspect they might have some other quantity parameter in the deluxe class that doesn't get the same value.

Comment: Then the code the OP has posted is not the code he is running, hence we can not continue trying to help.

Comment: @A.Abramov I edited and put all the code in the class `Deluxe` there

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Emphasis on **minimal**. (Tips: Delete the prompts and instead hard code variable values. Delete methods not directly related to the problem. It doesn't matter if your program is sensible after minimization, just that it does something you don't expect.)

Comment: @CherylPerry: ok, now you have a quantity variable, but it still is not related to the quantity variable in your main method, which is the one you read. You'll need to pass that value, or set it in the Deluxe class

Comment: @Stultuske i'm sorry i don't quite understand what are you trying to explain. I did set the variable in Deluxe class.

Comment: No you didn't, you added the variable, that's it. It'll keep the default value (0) until it is actually set. Like this line too: price = price * quantity * night; 
Since quantity is (always) 0, what value do you think price will get?

Comment: @Stultuske but the price calculated fine. Means that the quantity is being pass in the calculation to get the total value. I calculate it manually myself.  Or is it becuase i put have this another method in the main class to get the total value? I have edited and put my `calcTotal` there

Comment: @CherylPerry: since it's obviously not the code you are running,post the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity which you input here:

```
System.out.println("\nNow please enter how many of Deluxe Room you want to book.");
quantity = scan.nextInt();
```

Goes into `main(String[] args).quantity` that's defined here:

```
public class Hotel
{
....
public static void main(String[] args)
{
...
int quantity, sale,night;
 ...
 }
```

The quantity that you check here:

```
if (quantity > 0){...}
```

Is a different parameter - it's `Deluxe.quantity` and is defined here:

```
public class Deluxe implements Register
{
int quantity,night;
...
}
```

Those two parameters have no relation. If you want them both to be the same, you need to pass to class `Deluxe` the `main(String[] args).quantity` parameter. You can do this via your own constructor under `Hotel.main(String[] args)`, like so:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
Hotel run = new Hotel();
int quantity, sale,night;
Register family = new Family();
Register suite = new Suite();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter customer's name:");
String name = input.next();

quantity = run.enterItems();
Register deluxe = new Deluxe(quantity,0,0); // entering the default value for the other two parameters like the empty constructor would leave them.
if(run.count != 0)
{
System.out.println("\nHotel Reservation Payment");
System.out.println("============================");
System.out.println("Customer name: " + name);
deluxe.displayInfo(); //supposed to print the details
family.displayInfo(); //supposed to print the details
suite.displayInfo();  //supposed to print the details
System.out.println("The final total is RM" + fmt.format(run.calcTotal()));
}
else
{
  System.out.println("No items entered.");
  run.enterItems();
}
```

if you change your `enterItems()` function to return the quantity parameter you need, like so:

```
public int enterItems()
{
int type, quantity, sale,night;
double price;
.........
System.out.println("\nNow please enter how many of Deluxe Room you want to book.");
quantity = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("\nHow many night?");
night = scan.nextInt();
items[count] = new Deluxe(quantity,sale,night);
count++;
return quantity;
}
```

Notice, this solves this only for the quantity parameter. if you need more, you might need to return the `Deluxe` structure from `enterItems()`. Good luck!

Comment: There is no 'Hotel.Quantity'. In the Hotel class, in the main method, there is a local variable quantity. Your explanation make it sound as if there is a 'Quantity' variable on class level (either static or instance), which there isn't.

Comment: @Stultuske Editted, thank you.

Comment: @A.Abramov i tried to return quantity value in `enterItems()` but it says unexpected return value

Comment: @CherylPerry without seeing how you exactly changed your code, we can only guess as to what is going wrong

Comment: @CherylPerry Make sure the function header looks like so : `public int enterItems()`

Comment: Alright got it thankss!